# Nested function or calling function in a function

Tags: c, function, nested

So, I'm not sure how to start, so I'll start with some code:

```
    int main()
{
    system("cls");
    printf( "1. D4\n" );
    printf( "2. D6\n" );
    printf( "3. D8\n" );
    printf( "4. Exit\n" );
    printf( "Selection: " );
    scanf( "%d", &input );
    switch ( input ) {
        case 1:            
            roll_d4();
            break;
```

First off, I have this, and when I pick a selection, it works to get me to the function I wanted. So when I get to the D4 function, I have this:

```
void roll_d4() {
system("cls");
printf("How many D4 do you want to roll?\n");
printf("Enter a number 1-20");
printf("\nSelection: ");
scanf("%d", &input);
switch (input){
    case 5:
    exit(0);
    d4_number();
}
```

Now, every time I try to run this, it doesn't like the `d4_number();` and says it's an implicit declaration. I'm just trying to let you pick a selection and have it go to the next part in the code, in this case a function that will actually roll a die rather than being a menu like this one. But doing it this way isn't working, and I'm at a loss at what to do.

Edit: Code addition. Here's the full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
char response;
    int sum = 0;
    time_t t;
    int result;

    int die_d4_1 = 0;
    int die_d4_2 = 0;
    int die_d4_3 = 0;
    int die_d4_4 = 0;
    int die_d4_5 = 0;
    int input;

void roll_d4() {
    system("cls");
    printf("How many D4 do you want to roll?\n");
    printf("Enter a number 1-20");
    printf("\nSelection: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    switch (input){
        case 5:
        exit(0);
        d4_number(0);
    }
}
void roll_d6()
{
    printf( "How many D6 do you want to roll?" );
}
void roll_d8()
{
    printf( "How many D8 do you want to roll?" );
}

void d4_number(){
    printf("How many d4 do you want to roll?");
}

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    printf( "1. D4\n" );
    printf( "2. D6\n" );
    printf( "3. D8\n" );
    printf( "4. Exit\n" );
    printf( "Selection: " );
    scanf( "%d", &input );
    switch ( input ) {
        case 1:            /* Note the colon, not a semicolon */
            roll_d4();
            break;
        case 2:          
            roll_d6();
            break;
        case 3:         
            roll_d8();
            break;
        case 4:        
            printf( "Thanks for playing!\n" );
            break;
        default:            
            printf( "Bad input, quitting!\n" );
            break;
    }
    getchar();

}
```

It's obviously very incomplete, but I'm just trying to solve this problem before adding more.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've defined your `d4_number()` function. (If you have, then you haven't shown us all your code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I feel like an idiot. All I had to do was move the declaration:

```
        void d4_number(){
    printf("How many d4 do you want to roll?");
}
```

above

```
void roll_d4() {
system("cls");
printf("How many D4 do you want to roll?\n");
printf("Enter a number 1-20");
printf("\nSelection: ");
scanf("%d", &input);
switch (input){
    case 5:
    d4_number(0);
}
```

so that it was declared before calling...I feel really dumb for this, but thanks everyone for the quick responses!

Answer (score 2):

You need to give d4_number() a prototype, before the call, so the compiler know what arguments it takes and what it returns.
Otherwise it still links (for historical reasons) and assumes it returns an int.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a closer look at this code

```
switch (input){
    case 5:
    exit(0);
    d4_number(0);
}
```

you can notice that before `d4_number` function there is an `exit` function invoked. In that case `d4_number` function has never a chance to execute because  the whole program stops and exits with `0` as a return code.

Other issue is that `d4_number` function definition does not accept any arguments, but in statement `d4_number(0)` there is one extra parameter passed.

Comment: I had forgotten that wasn't commented out. When I remove it and try to compile I get the same error: "In function 'roll_d4':
case_break.c:32:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'd4_number' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   d4_number();"